# Outline hovering effect issues on stacked divs

Tags: html, css

I have a list of divs that have a one pixel outline around them, when hovered on the div the outline for that div changes color. As expected, since the divs stack on top of one another the borders stack and will become and extra pixel thicker. I add a 1px margin to the top in order to avoid this, but this ruins the hovering effect.

Here is an basic example of what I'm doing and the issue with the hover 
http://jsbin.com/UcOTelUH/1/edit?html,css,output

When hovering all sides change color as they should except for the bottom since it's overlapped. Is there a way to avoid this using sibling selectors or some other trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (**[see here](http://jsbin.com/akOJANOb/1/edit)**):

```
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

div:hover{
  border-color:red;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Or if you want to use the `outline` property instead of `border`, use:

```
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

div:hover{
  outline-color:red;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks! It's always the smallest things haha.

Comment: No worries, its an easy one to miss